# Android simple animation not working

Tags: android, animation, rotation, imageview

I want to make a custom class which will be rotated every time the view is visible.

```
public class SpinningLoadingView extends ImageView {

public SpinningLoadingView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    if (!isInEditMode()) initialize();
}
private void initialize() {
    setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_loading);
    post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            rotateAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
            SpinningLoadingView.this.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
        }
    });
}
public SpinningLoadingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    if (!isInEditMode()) initialize();
}
```

}

Even If I remove te runnable and post and just start the animation in the initialize method, my custom view won't be rotated. (but the image is set).

What is the problem?

Comment: how long should your animation last?

Comment: Forever. Is like a loading image that will spin forever

Comment: i mean speed: how long would it take to rotate from 30 to 90 degrees?

Comment: Edited to 0 , 360.. same problem

Comment: ok: how long would you want it to rotate from 0 to 360 degrees?  fast,  slow,  how long in seconds?

Comment: 1s / rotation maybe ? my problem is that i don't set the time ?

Comment: se tell your animation to last one second and repeat that step forever

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set duration to your animation:

```
rotateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
```